Salesforce LWC that is subscribed to a platform event doesn't let me use RefreshApex as the element is undefined
I have a screen flow that guides a user to create a billing record in Salesforce.
The last button creates the record and also sends a platform event.
My LWC is designed to show the totals e.g. Amount, Hours. The LWC successfully subscribes to the event and receives the payload of true.
When I get this payload I would like to refresh the LWC to show the latest totals.
I have noticed that element that is used in the setup for RefreshApex - this.dataToRefresh shows  undefined in the console log.
What am I missing?
Console Log
this.dataToRefresh at initialisation  [{…}]0: {totalAmount: 30000, totalHours: 120}length: 1[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

billingOverview.js:1 this.dataToRefresh  undefined

LWC
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { subscribe } from 'lightning/empApi';
import getBillingData from '@salesforce/apex/BillingData.getBillingData';
import TOTAL_HOURS_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Total_Hours__c";
import HOURLY_RATE_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Hourly_Rate__c";

const fields = [TOTAL_HOURS_FIELD, HOURLY_RATE_FIELD];

export default class BillingOverview extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
 
    subscription = {};
    @api channelName = '/event/Billing_Created__e';
    
    billingData;
    dataToRefresh;
    totalHoursInvoiced;
    totalAmountInvoiced

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields })
    opportunity;

    @wire(getBillingData,  { recordId: '$recordId' })
    wiredBillingData(result) {
        if (result.data) {
            this.dataToRefresh = result;
            this.billingData = result.data;
            console.log('this.dataToRefresh at initialisation ',this.billingData);
            this.totalHoursInvoiced = this.billingData[0].totalHours;
            this.totalAmountInvoiced = this.billingData[0].totalAmount;
        } else if (result.error) {
          console.log('Error - ',result.error);
        }
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.handleSubscribe();
    }

    handleSubscribe() {
        const messageCallback = function (response) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
            if(obj.data.payload.Created__c === true) {
                // window.location.reload(); 
                console.log('this.dataToRefresh ',this.dataToRefresh);
                refreshApex(this.dataToRefresh);
            }
        };
 
        subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then(response => {
            this.subscription = response;
        });
    }
    
    get totalHours () {
        return getFieldValue(this.opportunity.data, TOTAL_HOURS_FIELD);
    }

    get totalValue () {
        return Number(getFieldValue(this.opportunity.data, HOURLY_RATE_FIELD)) * Number(getFieldValue(this.opportunity.data, TOTAL_HOURS_FIELD));
    }

    get hoursInvoiced () {
        return this.totalHoursInvoiced;
    }

    get amountInvoiced () {
        return this.totalAmountInvoiced;
    }

    get hoursRemaining () {
        return getFieldValue(this.opportunity.data, TOTAL_HOURS_FIELD) - this.totalHoursInvoiced;
    }

    get valueRemaining () {
        return (Number(getFieldValue(this.opportunity.data, HOURLY_RATE_FIELD)) * Number(getFieldValue(this.opportunity.data, TOTAL_HOURS_FIELD))) - this.totalAmountInvoiced;
    }
}

If I just include a window.location.refresh() instead of the RefreshApex then the whole page reloads. This is not ideal.
UPDATE
After doing some more reading I now understand that "this" is not pointing to where I though it was. It is pointing to the following which makes sense.
How do I pass in my dataToRefresh property so that RefreshApex will work?
This points to the following:
this
{id: '_1712072762310_8074', channel: '/event/Billing_Created__e', replayId: 13710, callback: ƒ}
callback
:
ƒ ()
channel
:
"/event/Billing_Created__e"
id
:
"_1712072762310_8074"
replayId
:
13710
[[Prototype]]
:
Object
UPDATE 3 March 2024
In my case I decided not to use the connectedCallBack. I called the handleSubscribe() from within my wire function so that I knew that my dataToRefresh property was populated.
This means that I can now access the property and the refreshApex() now works.
Updated code:
@wire(getBillingData,  { recordId: '$recordId' })
    wiredBillingData(result) {
        if (result.data) {
            this.dataToRefresh = result;
            this.billingData = result.data;
            this.totalHoursInvoiced = this.billingData[0].totalHours;
            this.totalAmountInvoiced = this.billingData[0].totalAmount;
            this.handleSubscribe(this.dataToRefresh);
        } else if (result.error) {
          console.log('Error - ',result.error);
        }
    }
handleSubscribe(dataToRefresh) {
        const messageCallback = function (response) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
            if(obj.data.payload.Created__c === true) {
                refreshApex(dataToRefresh);
            }
        };
 
        subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then(response => {
            this.subscription = response;
        });
    }
    

